# Correct graphical representation of a discrete function (PMF)

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I have a list: `{1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5}`.  I want to plot the percentage occurrence of elements in the whole list.

So the list plot I want to do is:

```
list={{1,1/10},{2,2/10},{3,4/10},{4,2/10},{5,1/10}};
ListPlot[list]
```

What is the name of this kind of plot in *Mathematica*?

How should I do it in *Mathematica* 7?

Comment: What type of plot do you want? Like a bar graph?

Comment: Yes. Like a bar graph.

Comment: @wolfies How do I move it?

Answer (score 5):

Given:

```
lis = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5}
 m  = Length[lis];
```

... then:

```
ListPlot[ Map[ {#[[1]], #[[2]]/m} &, Tally[lis]], Filling -> Axis]
```

is a correct representation of the discrete pmf:

[image]
<sub>(source: [org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/tallyho.png))</sub>

If you have the mathStatica add-on for *Mathematica*, one can do this even more simply with:

```
FrequencyPlotDiscrete[lis, 1]
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/tallyho2.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks again.  This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 5):

```
data = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5};
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[data];

DistributionDomain[dist]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)

dist["Weights"]
(* {1/10, 1/5, 2/5, 1/5, 1/10} *)

Transpose[{dist["Domain"], dist["Weights"]}]
(* {{1, 1/10}, {2, 1/5}, {3, 2/5}, {4, 1/5}, {5, 1/10}} *)
```

**Properties**

```
{#, {dist[#]}} & /@ dist["Properties"] // TableForm
```

[image]

**PMF**

```
Table[{x, PDF[dist, x]}, {x, 0, 6, .5}] // 
   Transpose // TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {{x, PDF[x]}, None}] & // Style[#, 16] &
```

[image]

***Plotting with `ListPlot`***

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{dist["Domain"], dist["Weights"]}],
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> {0, .5},
    Filling -> Axis,  FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Blue, Thickness[.01]]]
```

[image]

***Plotting with `DiscretePlot`***

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[dist, x], {x, DistributionDomain[dist]},
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], ImageSize -> 500, 
    FillingStyle -> Thickness[.01], PlotRange -> {0, .5}]
```

[image]

Comment: excellent! but you should automate the "6"

Comment: @eldo, thank you.. done..

Answer (score 3):

```
Histogram[{1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5}, {1}, "Probability"]
```

Or how about this:

```
BarChart[#[[2]]/Total[#[[2]]], ChartLabels -> #[[1]]] &[Transpose[Tally[{1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5}]]]
```

Comment: Can't agree with this. A histogram (as provided) shows a continuous mass from 1 to 2, and from 2 to 3 etc ... whereas the problem at hand is discrete, with a discrete mass at the points  x= {1,2,3,4,5}, and nothing in between them.

Comment: @heropup Thanks for the answer. I tried your method and it worked OK.  wolfies is right, I want to have all the density concentrated at the discrete points.